How can a PDF with text and images be generated
The following snippet generates a pdf with text but the image is distorted like this
Seems the required image should be a .jpg. When I used a .png, not even a distorted image was showing in the pdf.
public static void createPdf() {
    try {
        //Image image = Image.createImage("/icon.png");
        Image image = Image.createImage("/Logo.jpg");
        EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);
        byte[] imageData = encodedImage.getImageData();

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        content.append("%PDF-1.4\n");
        content.append("1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj\n");
        content.append("2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj\n");
        content.append("3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 520 800]/Contents 6 0 R>>endobj\n");
        content.append("4 0 obj<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0 R>>>>endobj\n");
        content.append("5 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>endobj\n");
        content.append("6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream\n");
        content.append("BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Codename One)Tj ET\n");
        content.append("BT /F1 20 Tf 100 700 Td (Using one codebase, build)Tj ET\n");
        content.append("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 660 Td (Android apps)Tj ET\n");
        content.append("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 640 Td (iOS apps)Tj ET\n");
        content.append("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");
        content.append("512 0 0 512 4 50 cm\n");
        content.append("/Im0 Do\n");
        content.append("endstream\n");
        content.append("endobj\n");
        content.append("7 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 512/Height 512/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/DCTDecode/Length 132959>>stream\n");
        
        content.append(new String(imageData));

        content.append("endstream\n");
        content.append("endobj\n");
        content.append("\n");
        content.append("xref\n");
        content.append("0 8\n");
        content.append("0000000000 65535 f \n");
        content.append("0000000009 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000052 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000102 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000197 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000255 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000316 00000 n \n");
        content.append("0000000609 00000 n \n");
        content.append("trailer\n");
        content.append("<</Size 8/Root 1 0 R>>\n");
        content.append("startxref\n");
        content.append("133724\n");
        content.append("%%EOF\n");
        
        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String pdfPath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "Test2.pdf";
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath))) {
            w.write(content.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}

The generated pdf is saved in app storage directory home/.cn1
How can the required raw image data be extracted from the image so that image can show without distortion?
Edit: This question is a bit different from this since I need the image binary data to be generated/created and inserted to the pdf programmatically not manually
EDIT
Writing pdf content directly without appending to a StringBuilder results to this Test7.pdf. That is
private void createPdf7() {
    try {
        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String pdfPath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "Test7.pdf";
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath))) {

            w.write("%PDF-1.4\n");
            w.write("1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj\n");
            w.write("3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 520 800]/Contents 6 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("4 0 obj<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0 R>>>>endobj\n");
            w.write("5 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>endobj\n");
            w.write("6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Codename One)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 100 700 Td (Using one codebase, build)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 660 Td (Android apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 640 Td (iOS apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("512 0 0 512 4 50 cm\n");
            w.write("/Im0 Do\n");
            w.write("endstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");
            w.write("7 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 50/Height 50/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 132959>>stream\n");

            InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), "/Logo.jpg");
            //InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), "/icon.jpeg");
            //InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(this.getClass(), "/icon.png");

            int nextChar = is.read();
            if (nextChar == -1) {
                //return null;
            }

            while (nextChar > -1) {
                //Log.p("Char " + (char) nextChar);
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = is.read();
            }
            w.write("\nendstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");
            w.write("\n");
            w.write("xref\n");
            w.write("0 8\n");
            w.write("0000000000 65535 f \n");
            w.write("0000000009 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000052 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000102 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000197 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000255 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000316 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000609 00000 n \n");
            w.write("trailer\n");
            w.write("<</Size 8/Root 1 0 R>>\n");
            w.write("startxref\n");
            w.write("133724\n");
            w.write("%%EOF\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}

What I am still missing for the image to show correctly?
EDIT
Opening this JSjpegSample-with image.pdf with Linux Text Editor shows the following image data stream encoding. Note some readable text like JFIF Photoshop 7.0

In Codename One simulator, this encoding is close to how SQLite database file is encoded. SQLite database open with Linux Text Editor shows the following. Note some readable text like SQLite format 3 CREATE TABLE

How can a .jpeg to be added to a pdf be encoded same way as SQLite database file?

This question is similar to: How to insert an image into PDF source code. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is little, or no, information on the image size that Eric uses. So, how would anyone know if this is correct?  Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 512/Height 512

I think @KJ is correct. I suggest that instead of building a String and using append you should write directly to the InputStream. Convert the initial part to UTF-8 bytes and then write the image bytes manually. Then add the rest of the text as a byte array.

In a NotePad, I have just open these pdf you shared and compared them with my latest Test7.pdf I had shared above. Seems image data is almost similar. Is it possible that the image data is now okay and that something else is the reason why image is distorted?

NotePad is in windows OS. However in Linux Text Editor the image stream you shared starts with \FF\D8\FF\E0\00JFIF\00\00H\00H\00\00\FF\E1wExif\00\00MM\00*\00\00\00\00 but what I shared starts with
ÿØÿà JFIF  H H  ÿØÿà wExif  MM *                  b       j(       1 

@Eric JFIF is the standard JPEG header, From the bytes you listed it seems that PDF encodes the bytes rather than writes them directly. I'm not familiar enough with the encoding but it looks like the code writes \FF instead of byte value 255 etc. It seems to write the valid ascii range characters like JFIF "as is". This should be pretty simple to encode by checking the range and using Integer.toHex().

@KJ It doesn't "lie". The values are written as bytes rather than encoded. A simple solution would probably be to write each byte as stream.write("\"); stream.write(Integer.toHexString(byteValue & 0xff)). That simplistic solution might work as is.

@ShaiAlmog writing bytes using  byte[] imageArr = encodedImage.getImageData();                 for (int i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {                     w.write("\\");                     w.write(Integer.toHexString(imageArr[i] & 0xff));                 }  results to this
Test8HexDecode.pdf where image is still distorted.

@KJ I don't know since I have no idea about the PDF format. However, it seems the file is meant to be a binary file and you're using a Writer instead of a stream. A writer will always manipulate data and encode the unicode characters in a particular way, I'm assuming that you've taken this code from somewhere, if you have a reference to the original code I might be able to help with the Java equivalent.

@KJ Windows-1252 encoding set in this sample tries but some hexadecimal are read as ?. But this gave me an idea to try other encodings like ISO-8859-1 which worked. Thank you for being part of this discussion and sharing knowledge about PDF.

And find some reference (followi.e.: How to browse the internal PDF structure in Adobe Acrobat?) , to find how images are part of a PDF structure

The following successfully adds image to the pdf document. The requirements include:

Create a jpeg image using
EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);
This is useful since png images can be converted to jpeg

Create a ByteArrayInputStream from image bytes. Using ByteArrayInputStream, image bytes are directly written as characters to the pdf.

Set ISO-8859-1 encoding in OutputStreamWriter. This encoding ensured all characters in the image bytes are read as expected by Filter/DCTDecode.
Windows-1252 encoding also tries but some hexadecimal are read as ?.



    private void createPdf11() {
        try {
            //Image image = Image.createImage("/Logo.jpg");
            Image image = Image.createImage("/android_logo.png");
            //Image image = Image.createImage("/ios_logo.png");
            
            //create a jpeg encoded image
            EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);
            byte[] imageData = encodedImage.getImageData();

            //get image width, height & length
            int imageWidth = encodedImage.getWidth();
            int imageHeight = encodedImage.getHeight();
            int imageLength = imageData.length;
            
            //create ByteArrayInputStream from image byte array
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

            FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
            String pdfPath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "Test12.pdf";
            try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath), "ISO-8859-1")) {
                w.write("%PDF-1.7\n");
                w.write("1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj\n");
                w.write("2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj\n");
                w.write("3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 520 800]/Contents 6 0 R>>endobj\n");
                w.write("4 0 obj<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0 R>>>>endobj\n");
                w.write("5 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>endobj\n");
                w.write("6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream\n");
                w.write("BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Codename One)Tj ET\n");
                w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 100 700 Td (Using one codebase, build)Tj ET\n");
                w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 660 Td (Android apps)Tj ET\n");
                w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 640 Td (iOS apps)Tj ET\n");
                w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");
                w.write("50 0 0 50 4 540 cm\n");
                w.write("/Im0 Do\n");
                w.write("endstream\n");
                w.write("endobj\n");
                w.write("7 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width " + imageWidth + "/Height " + imageHeight + "/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/DCTDecode/Length " + imageLength + ">>stream\n");

                //read the next byte of data from ByteArrayInputStream in int range 0 - 255
                int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
                while (nextChar > -1) {
                    //convert int to char and add it to char array
                    char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                    //write char array
                    w.write(charArray);
                    nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
                }

                w.write("\nendstream\n");
                w.write("endobj\n");
                w.write("\n");
                w.write("xref\n");
                w.write("0 8\n");
                w.write("0000000000 65535 f \n");
                w.write("0000000009 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000052 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000102 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000197 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000255 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000316 00000 n \n");
                w.write("0000000609 00000 n \n");
                w.write("trailer\n");
                w.write("<</Size 8/Root 1 0 R>>\n");
                w.write("startxref\n");
                w.write("133724\n");
                w.write("%%EOF\n");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.p("Error " + e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    }



This creates Test11.pdf with text and image in the app home path directory home/.cn1

To add a 2nd image, another object to contain it eg 8 0 obj is needed. This object number is then added to 4 0 obj as /Im1 8 0 R. Finally the position of 2nd image is also set in 6 0 obj as  w.write("q 50 0 0 50 4 460 cm /Im1 Do Q\n");. That is,
private void createPdf13() {
    try {
        Image image = Image.createImage("/Logo.jpg");
        //create a jpeg encoded image
        EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);
        byte[] imageData = encodedImage.getImageData();

        int imageWidth = encodedImage.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = encodedImage.getHeight();
        int imageLength = imageData.length;
        //create ByteArrayInputStream from image byte array
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

        Image image2 = Image.createImage("/android_logo.png");
        //create a jpeg encoded image
        EncodedImage encodedImage2 = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image2, true);
        byte[] imageData2 = encodedImage2.getImageData();
        int imageWidth2 = encodedImage2.getWidth();
        int imageHeight2 = encodedImage2.getHeight();
        int imageLength2 = imageData2.length;
        //create ByteArrayInputStream from image byte array
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData2);

        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String pdfPath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "Test13.pdf";
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath), "ISO-8859-1")) {
            w.write("%PDF-1.7\n");
            w.write("1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj\n");
            w.write("3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 520 800]/Contents 6 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("4 0 obj<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0 R/Im1 8 0 R>>>>endobj\n");
            w.write("5 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>endobj\n");
            w.write("6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream\n");
            w.write("q\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Codename One)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 100 700 Td (Using one codebase, build)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 660 Td (Android apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 640 Td (iOS apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("q 50 0 0 50 4 540 cm /Im0 Do Q\n");
            w.write("q 50 0 0 50 4 460 cm /Im1 Do Q\n");
            w.write("Q\n");
            w.write("endstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");

            w.write("7 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width " + imageWidth + "/Height " + imageHeight + "/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/DCTDecode/Length " + imageLength + ">>stream\n");
            //read the next byte of data from ByteArrayInputStream in int range 0 - 255
            int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            while (nextChar > -1) {
                //convert int to char and add it to char array
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                //write char array
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
            w.write("\nendstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");

            w.write("8 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width " + imageWidth2 + "/Height " + imageHeight2 + "/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/DCTDecode/Length " + imageLength2 + ">>stream\n");
            //read the next byte of data from ByteArrayInputStream in int range 0 - 255
            int nextChar2 = byteArrayInputStream2.read();
            while (nextChar2 > -1) {
                //convert int to char and add it to char array
                char[] charArray2 = {(char) nextChar2};
                //write char array
                w.write(charArray2);
                nextChar2 = byteArrayInputStream2.read();
            }
            w.write("\nendstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");

            w.write("\n");
            w.write("xref\n");
            w.write("0 9\n");
            w.write("0000000000 65535 f \n");
            w.write("0000000009 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000052 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000102 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000197 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000255 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000316 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000609 00000 n \n");
            w.write("trailer\n");
            w.write("<</Size 9/Root 1 0 R>>\n");
            w.write("startxref\n");
            w.write("133724\n");
            w.write("%%EOF\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}

Which generates Test13.pdf

I can programmatically get length of the image bytes array which equals 21223. I can also programmatically set it as the length of the image stream. I can also programmatically get and set image height & width.

What is value 746? What is  value 19?

Just to confirm if I understand. Do you mean 746 = bytes length from line w.write("%PDF-1.7\n") to line w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");

Do you mean 19 = byte length from line w.write("\nendstream\n") to line w.write("\n"); ?

@KJ I am yet to calculate and set the actual size of xref. But right now I have edited the answer setting actual width, height & length of the image to the generated pdf. Eg. Test12.pdf

In the meantime I am also trying to add multiple images to the same pdf without success. I have tried to create 2 image streams but only 1st image shows. How can multiple images be added?

@KJ I have following your instructions to add a 2nd image by adding a 8th object but only 1st image shows as in this Test13.pdf. I have also  tried to add another object before the 2nd image but only 1st image shows as in this Test14.pdf. What is wrong in these pdf? Can you please edit the pdf and correct the parts that are wrong?

Writer class doesn't have a function to read length of written bytes. I will have to figure out a way to read that.

Thank you for the assist & advice. Both are now successfully generated with multiple images. I will edit the answer to add this functionality. I will also work on calculating the actual xref  length

@KJ I have created this separate question to discuss how to calculate xref length.

Thank you. I will look into this Test 20 Questions.pdf

@KJ Thank you for this update
